# Define member variables in functions blindly

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, variables, declaration

I am having a bit of an issue with a current task of mine. Basically, I am given an XML file and am trying to parse it for key information. For example, some lines will be like this:

```
<IPAddress>123.45.67</IPAddress>
```

And I am to get the value of 123.45.67, nothing too bad at all. I was told not to use a XML parser and just parse it manually, which was pretty easy. However, I am having issues with the second part of the task. Basically, I am to make a class with certain member variables and declare them based on the values I parse. So let's say the class is called Something and there is a member variable called IPAddress. I am to then update the value of IPAddress to 123.45.67 so when someone calls Something.IPAddress in the main method, it returns 123.45.67. This was my initial attempt at it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;

class Something
{
   public:
    string location;
    string IPAddress;
    string theName;
    int aValue;

    //loop through the array from the method below
    void fillContent(string* array)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < array->size(); i++)
        {
              string line = array[i];
              if((line.find("<") != std::string::npos) && (line.find(">")!= std::string::npos)) 
              {
                 unsigned first = line.find("<");
                 unsigned last = line.find(">");
                 string strNew = line.substr (first + 1, last - first - 1); //this line will get the key, in this case, "IPAddress"
             unsigned newfirst = line.find(">");
                 unsigned newlast = line.find_last_of("<");
             string strNew2 = line.substr(newfirst + 1, newlast - newfirst - 1); //this line will get the value, in this case, "123.45.67"
                if(strNew == "IPAddress")
                {
                    IPAddress = strNew2; //set the member variable to the IP Address
                }
              }
        }
    }

    //this method will create an array where each element is a line from the xml
        void fillVariables()
    {
        string line;
        ifstream myfile ("content.xml");
        long num = //function that gets size that I didn't add to make code shorter!;
        string *myArray;
        myArray = new string[num];
        string str1 = "";
        string strNew2 = "";
        int counter = 0;
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while ( getline (myfile,line) )
            {
            myArray[counter] = line;
                counter++;
            }
            myfile.close();
        }
        fillContent(myArray);
    }

};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Something local;
  local.fillVariables();
  cout << local.IPAddress<< endl; // should return "123.45.67"
  return 0;
}
```

Now this does do what I want it to do, however, you can see I need the if statement. Assuming I have at least 20 of these member variables, having 20 if-statements would be annoying and just frowned upon. Is there any other way I could somehow access the member variables from the class? Sorry if my question was long, I just wanted to make sure everything that is needed to understand the question is provided! Please let me know if anything crucial that may not be there should be added.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be considered bad style, but I usually just do:

```
// at the top of the 'fillContent' function
std::map<string, string*> varmap{
    {"IPAddress", &IPAddress},
    {"AnotherField", &AnotherField}
 };
 // If you're not using C++11, you can also try:
 // std::map<string, string*> varmap;
 // varmap["IPAddress"] = &IPAddress;
 // varmap["AnotherField"] = &AnotherField;

 // parsing code goes here
 *varmap[strNew] = strNew2;
```

Comment: So would I add the `std::map<string, string*> varmap{
    {"IPAddress", &IPAddress},
    {"AnotherField", &AnotherField}
 };` at the very top and just add all of the member variables into this map? Or would this be inserted into the fillContent function? I'm assuming into the function, correct?

Comment: @user2397837 At the top of the `fillContent` function.

Comment: Let me give it a shot. I'll let you know how it goes! I was thinking of using maps, but haven't used them for some time so a bit unfamiliar with them.

Comment: All I have to include when using maps is <map>, correct? I'm keep on getting a "extended initialized lists only available with ...."

Comment: @user2397837 Try also passing `-std=c++11` to the compiler.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? No clear way when I searched it on google.

Comment: @user2397837 What OS are you running, and what IDE are you using? I admit I may have been slightly vague. :)

Comment: I am on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 desktop and am using Gedit with the terminal. It's fine! I like the map idea if it works out. No one else has added any suggestions yet anyways!

Comment: g++ -o main sample.cpp

Comment: @user2397837 Use `g++ -o main -std=c++11 sample.cpp`. I'll edit the answer for an alternate method that doesn't require the extra option.

Comment: @user2397837 Done! Glad I could help. ;)

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos do you know if doing something like this is possible if creating the functions outside of the class? The member variables are still public, so I'd like to think it's possible, but would I be able to effectively update Something.location outside of the Something class.

Comment: @user2677095 It should be. Did you run into any trouble?

Comment: Yeah, I basically ran the same exact code but it's not properly dereferencing I guess. When I run through all the keys and values, all of the values are in 0x... format.

Comment: @user2677095 The values are pointers, so you need to dereference them; otherwise, you end up printing the memory addresses.

Comment: So right now I'm assigning the member variables like this still: 

`*varmap[strNew] = strNew2;`

Comment: And I am dereferencing them in my iterator like this `&iterator->second`

Comment: @user2677095 I meant when printing them. :) Just like you have to deref when assigning, you also have to when printing, e.g. `std::cout << *theValue;`.

Comment: @user2677095 You need to do `*it->second`; your example is taking the address of the pointer.

Comment: Tried that!! Seems to be printing out blank lines :O

Comment: Is my      `*varmap[strNew] = strNew2;` correct though?

Comment: @user2677095 It should be. I think your issue might be somewhere else. If you print `strNew2`, do you also get blank lines? If so, then the issue is definitely in the code that assigns to `strNew2`.

Comment: So the map being declared outside the class structure should also be fine? And I'd create a local Something var and call on the member variables like this?

`Something local; varmap["AnotherField"] = &local.AnotherField;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86942/discussion-between-user2677095-and-kirbyfan64sos).